# how do i convert bytes into decimal?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am working on an application in which c# handler sends bytes data to flash with some int values concatinated at the end as a binary write.

C# Code:

```
 int pageNumber = 2;
 context.Response.BinaryWrite(Image);
 context.Response.BinaryWrite(pageNumber);
```

I action script3 i am receiving that byte array and need to get the pagenumber from the bytes.

AS3 Code:

```
 var imageData:ByteArray = event.target.data;
 var pageN:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
 pageN.writeBytes(imageData, imageData.length - 4, 4);
```

How to convert pageN byte array into int .

Comment: Upvote for Vesper. But there is a cool algorithm called Double Dabble if you ever need to do that problem manually or in silicon. :)

Answer (score 5):

```
var yourInt:int=pageN.readInt();
```

Should do, if you have correctly specified the position of your int.